# How to apply Syntastic to PHP5.4 feature

Tags: php, vim

when I use [] instead of array() which is PHP5.4's new feature then Syntastic cause error 'Parse Error'

I want to avoid this error message.

Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Syntastic uses three programs to check your code: `php` itself, `phpmd` and `phpcs`. Verify which one(s) are actually used and see if and how it can be configured to get rid of this error.

Also, one, some or all of these programs may not be 5.4-ready.